# Stationary distribution of DTMC with infinite state space

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I am solving the stationary distirbution of a Discrete time Markov Chain with infinite state space. The state space is  $\{\pi^H_0,\pi^H_1,...,\pi^L_0,\pi^L_1,...\}$. The transition matrix has structure. I eventually reduce the system linear equations into the following two series. But feel no clue about how to start to solve them....
\begin{align*}
&\begin{cases}
&\pi^H_0=a\pi^H_1\\
&\pi^H_1=a\pi^H_0+a\pi^H_2+c\pi^L_0\\
&\pi^H_n=b\pi^H_{n-1}+a\pi^H_{n+1},~\forall~n\geq 2
\end{cases}~~
\begin{cases}
&\pi^L_0=c\pi^L_1\\
&\pi^L_1=b\pi^H_0+d\pi^L_0+c\pi^L_2\\
&\pi^L_n=d\pi^L_{n-1}+c\pi^L_{n+1},~\forall~n\geq 2
\end{cases}\\
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\pi^H_n+\pi^L_n)=1\\
&a+b=1,~c+d=1,~a,b,c,d~\mbox{are all positive constant }\{\pi^H_n\}_{n=0}^\infty~\mbox{and }\{\pi^L_n\}_{n=0}^\infty~\mbox{are all non-negative variables}
\end{align*}

Comment: "The state space is  $\{\pi^H_0,\pi^H_1,... ,\pi^L_0,\pi^L_1, ...\}$." You might mean that the state space is $$\{H,L\}\times\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$$

Comment: @Did Yes, sorry for my bad notation

Answer (score 1):

The recurrences in the third lines aren't coupled, so they can be solved with the standard *ansatz* $\pi_k^H=\lambda^k$:

$$
\lambda^n=b\lambda^{n-1}+a\lambda^{n+1}\;,
$$

which yields the characteristic equation

$$
a\lambda^2-\lambda+b=0
$$

(and likewise for $\pi^L$). This yields two linearly independent solutions each, for a total of $4$ free coefficients. The first two lines allow you to express the values for $n=1,2$ in terms of the initial values for $n=0$, yielding one condition each. That leaves two degrees of freedom, and normalization reduces this to one. This might be eliminated if one of the characteristic values has magnitude greater than $1$ and thus isn't suitable for representing probabilities.